# How to build a hash table with tokens produced by a lexer?

Tags: ocaml, lexer

I want to build a hash table with the lexemes produced by a lexer. The lexer is just a simple one, generated by the ocamllex. 
What I produced is the following code:

```
          ...
let ht = Hashtbl.create 300
let add_lexeme = function
  | "MINUS" -> Hashtbl.add ht "-" "BINOP"
  ...
  | "EOF" -> Hashtbl.add ht "eof" "EOF"

let main () =
   let lexbuf = set_filename "stdin" @@ Lexing.from_channel stdin in
   let rec make_table =
     | EOF -> add_lexeme EOF
     | x   -> add_lexeme x (tokens lexbuf)
   let () = main ()
```

Which is giving me syntax error in the make_table. However, I didn't like the overall structure of this code. I would like to know a better (and correct) way to encode this idea (I'm very new to ocaml).

Comment: You forgot to write `match` or `function` after `make_table =`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(* This is just an alias of the Hashtable module *)
module H = Hashtable

(* This function open a lexbuf and add the output to a hash table *)
let main () =
  let my_buf = set_filename "stdin" (Lexing.from_channel stdin) in
  let ht = H.create_hash 100 in
  let rec loop = function
    | EOF -> H.to_table EOF ht
    | x   -> (H.to_table x ht); loop (token my_buf)
  in
  loop (token my_buf);
  H.print_hash ht
  let () = main ()
```

Answer (score 2):

After you fix up many small problems, your code looks pretty OK to me at a high level. It iterates over all the lexemes of stdin, adding them to the table.

Some low-level comments:

As the commenters say, your definition of `make_table` doesn't make sense. It's not syntactically valid. Possibly you want:

```
let rec make_table = function
| EOF ...
```

Your `make_table` function doesn't have a recursive call, so it's just going to add one lexeme to the table. In fact there are no calls at all to `make_table`. You presumably want one recursive call and one call from `main`.

You are passing a value named `EOF` to add_lexeme, which expects two parameters, of which the first is a string. So, this isn't a valid call. Possibly you want `"EOF"` here. If so, you need to make sure your lexer returns `"EOF"` at the end of the file. (But what will it return if `EOF` actually shows up in the file?)

A lexical analyzer most often returns an algebraic type, not string. Your lexer is returning a string. But it can return any type you like.

The `@@` operator is such that `f @@ g x` is equivalent to `f (g x)`. In other words, it's mainly useful to avoid parentheses. If I look at this fragment:

```
let lexbuf = set_filename "stdin" @@ Lexing.from_channel stdin
```

I have a hard time deciding what it's doing. It's equivalent to this:

```
let lexbuf = set_filename "stdin" (Lexing.from_channel stdin)
```

There are quite a few problems here. There is a function `Lexing.set_filename` but you haven't supplied a module name. Unless you wrote your own function named `set_filename` this won't be a valid call.

Assuming you're calling `Lexing.set_filename`, this function returns unit. It doesn't make sense to set `lexbuf` to unit.

I suspect you essentially want `;` instead of `@@`:

```
 let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
 Lexing.set_filename lexbuf "stdin";
 (* and so on *)
```

You call a function named `tokens` that's not defined anywhere.

These are small problems, and you seem to be asking for more general comments. It would be easier to comment if you supplied a full, working example.

Comment: I answered the question with what I was trying to build, which is now working due to your helpful comments